# Keypress detection and sending in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, keypress, onkeypress

So what im looking to do is find if i have the space bar pressed at all and while it is i would like to have the space bar be released and then pressed again mutiple times with a delay of about 10 ms. i have tried to read and understand this link (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) but it is still confusing any help? im brand new to c# but i have some experience with pascal of which i have found very similar
(using visual studio 2015 due to my computer not allowing me to update to windows 8.1)

Comment: Pressing and releasing space bar is a physical action carried out by the user. So you can't have your code do _have the space bar be released and then pressed again mutiple times with a delay of about 10 ms._ What exactly is your question?

Comment: essentially having the progran simulate a keypress of the spacebar whilst i hold it or some other hotkey

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this? Are you wanting something to happen every 10 ms while the spacebar is pressed, besides just simulating spacebar presses?

Answer (score -1):

`10ms delay` mean 100 times per second, no one could do it.

Key events occur in the following order:

1. KeyDown
2. KeyPress
3. KeyUp

Events `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` use `KeyEventArgs`, while `KeyPress` is `KeyPressEventArgs`,

`KeyEventArgs` could details how many keys are pressed at same time. `KeyEventArgs.KeyCode` is `Keys` which is a `[Flags]` enum, it could contains multiple keys, like CTRL+SHift+F+G

if your hotkey is Ctrl+Shift+Space, you can check with:

```
var hotkeyPressed = e.Control && e.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.Space;
```

if your hotkey is Ctrl+F10+Space, you can check with:

```
var hotkeyPressed = e.Control && e.KeyCode == (Keys.Space | Keys.F10);
```

but do not use:

```
var hotkeyPressed = e.Control && e.KeyCode.HasFlag(Keys.F10) && e.KeyCode.HasFlag(Keys.Space); // e.KeyCode probably contains other flags
```

`KeyPressEventArgs.KeyChar` is a string, take a look source code, focus on its comments

```
  [ComVisible(true)]
  public class KeyPressEventArgs : EventArgs
  {
    ...
    /// <summary>Gets or sets the character corresponding to the key pressed.</summary>
    /// <returns>The ASCII character that is composed. For example, if the user presses SHIFT + K, this property returns an uppercase K.</returns>
    public char KeyChar { get; set; }
    ...
  }
```

to use which event, it depends on your requirement.
here is sample code in KeyDown:

```
    private int counting = 0, limit = 10;
    private void txt_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.KeyCode.HasFlag(Keys.Space)) //check if your expected key is pressed
        {
            counting = 0;
            return;
        }
        //start counting
        counting++;

        if (counting > limit)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            //do you business work, like: Send something somewhere

        }
        else
        {
            //do something else, like: show the number 'counting' in GUI
        }
    }
```

if you want limit timespan with next space, use a [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    private void txt_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        if (!e.KeyCode.HasFlag(Keys.Space))
        {
            counting = 0;
            return;
        }
        //start counting
        timer1.Start();
        counting++;

        if (counting > limit)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            //do you business work, like: Send something somewhere

        }
        else
        {
            //do something else, like: show the number 'counting' in GUI
        }
    }

    //timer1.Interval = 100; //100ms timeout. user has to press space again within 100ms
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counting = 0;
    }
```